# How to restrict editing of a google sheet by few users at a certain time everyday using java script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a google sheet. I want to restrict editing of my google sheet at a certain time everyday by few users using Java script. Kindly guide me.
Please find the below link for your reference.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fZBCGRBz-6l8TB_is9yl8hX9fqn88Piq3LD-s8sPOiY/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For this task you can benefit from making use of **Apps Script** - **Apps Script** is a powerful development platform which can be used to build web apps and automate tasks. What makes it special is the fact that it is easy to use and to create applications that integrate with G Suite.

Therefore, if you want to *restrict* the audience of your spreadsheet, you can use the [`removeEditor(emailAddress)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#removeeditoremailaddress) function, where *emailAddress* is the email address of the user you want to remove.

```
function removeEditor() {
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADHSEET_ID');
   spreadsheet.removeEditor('EDITOR_EMAIL_ADDRESS');
}
```

*As for running the script you create at a specific time* - fairly easy! Just create a [**time-driven trigger**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) which will run at the time chosen by you.

If you want to (re)allow the users who you have restricted to reuse the spreadsheet, you may need to create another trigger which will run *after* the previous one and re-add them to the editors list.

#### Reference

- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script);
- [Spreadsheet Class Apps Script removeEditor(emailAddress)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#removeeditoremailaddress);
- [Installable Triggers Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I can't use this function since I am looking to lock editing of certain cells of every single sheet at a certain time (Say between 3:00 am to 7:00 pm every day) is there any function to lock ranges. @ale13

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection).